# Why is the Ba'eir Heiteiv citing himself?

Tags: commentaries, shulchan-aruch

In the *Ba'eir Heiteiv* (באר היטב) commentary to the *Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chaim* 1, at the end of *s'if katan* 13, we find the words:

> וכן העתיק הבאר היטב אשר לפני ע״ש ולא ידעתי למה.
>
> And likewise, the *Ba'eir Heiteiv* that is in front of me brought/wrote [this idea], see there; and I do not know why.

Is this indeed a self-citation, and if so, why are his own words incomprehensible to him?

Comment: there was a previous sefer called be'er heitev, and that is what he is quoting--אשר לפני means "that preceded me," not "that is in front of me"

Comment: @wfb Can you point me to this sefer? If true, please post as an answer.

Comment: see the first paragraph of wikipedia here https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%98%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A7.D7.99.D7.A8.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.9E.D7.94.D7.93.D7.95.D7.A8.D7.95.D7.AA

Comment: @wfb Is this original באר היטב from רבי ישעיה בן רבי אברהם extant?

Comment: The Be'er Heitev commentary on Shulchan Aruch is also not just one author. Assuming that Orach Chaim was not the first tur of the commentary to be published, it is possible that he is referring to his colleague.

Comment: @magicker72 not sure if it's extant. I could not find it

Comment: @wfb Please post your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a previous sefer called Be'er Heitev, by R. Yeshayah b. R. Avraham, and that is what he is quoting--אשר לפני means "that preceded me," not "that is in front of me." See [here](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%98%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A7.D7.99.D7.A8.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.9E.D7.94.D7.93.D7.95.D7.A8.D7.95.D7.AA).

Comment: This seems very likely.  It would very nice to confirm this by finding a copy of this original באר היטב that contains the referenced comments.  But as mentioned above, perhaps it is no longer extant.

Comment: The Machon Yerushalyim edition of Shulchan Aruch has both Ba'er Heitevs printed together (the older one in square letters). I couldn't find this particular reference though. Look [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=147760&pagenum=148), maybe you'll find it.

Answer (score -1):

See beginning of the siman you quoted:

כמבואר בשלחן ערוך יורה דעה סי' ה'

He's talking about *Yoreh De'ah* which was written by a different person under the same commentary name. From Wikipedia:

> On the sections of Choshen Mishpat and Yoreh De'ah, the commentary was
>   written by Zechariah Mendel ben Aryeh Leib, a Polish rabbi who lived
>   in the 17th and 18th centuries.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but it seems to me that the reference to Yoreh De'ah does not carry forward to the discussion in the rest of the Ba'eir Heiteiv's comment. I also looked at the Ba'eir Heiteiv on that siman in Yoreh De'ah, and could not find a relevant comment.